# problem of the server

Tags: php, apache, web-config, apache-config

I would like to inform you about the another problem of the server. When we are updating the records, it updates the records in the database but when we want to access it on the browser through the frontend application of php files it is not displaying the updated records immediately. It takes the time of 15-20 minutes or more or sometimes we closes the browser and open the another browser then the updated records display there. I have already deleted the browser cache but the problem is still remains. I have checked this in the different different broswers like IE 6.0,7.0, chrome, safari, mozilla but unable to find the solution.

please suggest me what is the problem with the server?
please check this url :
http://www.nicee.org/trial/view.php

Comment: @Rahul Mehta -please check proxy cache, or apply random query string into the URL to force refresh the page content, also google "http header cache" how it works

Comment: Is it possible that you are opening a transaction for the update that you never close, and this then deadlocks your select?

Comment: @ajreal how to check proxy cache

Comment: @Rahul Mehta - http://www.ehow.com/how_5062892_disable-proxy-settings-firefox.html Or check the header response by the web page

Comment: @Paddy you are right but for closing the update what we should do ?

Comment: Is there is any php or apache configuration for solving this

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment slightly, I should point out that PHP isn't really something I'm familiar with, just the problem described sounded familiar.

To pseudo code it:

```
-- On Update

Open Transaction with Database

Run SQL command(s)

Close/commit transaction
```

If you don't do this final step (i.e. commiting the transaction & closing it), then it will remain open and will lock this table (depending on how your DB is set up).  You must ensure that it is always finished (rolled back if there is an error too).

From a quick google, this may be useful:

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/MySQL/Using-Transactions-with-MySQL-4.0-and-PHP/

Comment: Dear , i have changed the my table type to myisam but it is not the only database problem as i looked , as i change in any php code also , then also i need to refresh with query string , then only it show the changes could please suggest what exactly the problem is ?